# Magento 2.4.5 scandipwa install after run magneto upgrade command getting undefined method error?

Tags: magento2.4.5, pwa, magento2.4.6, pwa-theme

i have installed scandipwa theme in magento2.4.5, i am getting the `"Error: Call to undefined method Laminas\Validator\NotEmpty::setDisableTranslator()"` error.please check the attached screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe9Bf.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsN70.png

also i have tried same with magento 2.4.6. i am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error, somewhy it didn't adjust scandipwa version right with magento version, I noticed that the Scandipwa code was compatible with magento 2.4.6, so I just updated to magento 2.4.6-p1 and worked.

fix -
CMA - composer.json

From:

```
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.4-p1",
```

To:

```
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.6-p1",
```